# I'm having a hard time understanding the process for populating a multidimensional array. Why does my code print the one letter multiple times?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, printing, storing-data, storing-information

I was having a problem with this part while doing one of my assignments. So I decided to do a simple program to store and see if my understanding is correct but I am still having the same problems.

Initially, I didn't make the arrays pointers but that caused the program to crash immediately. So that is also why they are char pointers. If anyone can also explain why they need to be pointers and why it prints the way it does, that would be immensely helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char arr[2][2];
  char str[20];
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("%s\n", "please put in a string: ");
      scanf("%s\n", str[0]);
      arr[i][j] = str[0];
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("arr[%d][%d] == %s\n", i,j,arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the output that i got:

```
please put in a string:
pleasework
what
please put in a string:
s
please put in a string:
f
please put in a string:
g
arr[0][0] == f
arr[0][1] == f
arr[1][0] == f
arr[1][1] == f
```

Not the right outputs

Comment: Please turn on compiler warnings. `scanf("%s\n", str[0]);` is an error, you are passing an (uninitialised) `char` value to a function which is expecting a `char *` type, a *pointer* to `char`. It should be `scanf("%19s", str);` where the `19` prevents buffer overflow, and I removed the newline.

Comment: ^^^^^ if that doesn't spew a compiler warning at least, research your tools and find out what is needed to (a) turn up your warnings to pedantic levels, and (b) treat all warnings as errors. In nearly all cases, a warning should be considered an error, and in the case of a beginning C program *absolutely* **all** warnings should be treated as errors.

Comment: You are using the wrong format specifier `%s` in `printf("arr[%d][%d] == %s\n",i,j,arr[i][j]);` which should be `%c`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I updated my question with the current outputs. When I put %c is gave me some weird characters so I changed it to %s and it only prints the last one.

Comment: You've got `char *str[20]` — an array of 20 character pointers that do not point anywhere.  You need to make them point to somewhere with enough memory, or maybe you meant `char str[20];` — in which case you need to adjust the call to `scanf()` — you need to drop the `[0]` suffix.  Whatever else happens, you also need to make sure you read into separate memory for each string, or copy what was read into `str` into newly allocated space.

Comment: Please don't change the question, you asked what you asked. You didn't correctly copy from the comments anyway: rolled back.

Comment: @WeatherVane: When there are no answers, it is OK to change the question.  Comments are ephemeral; there's no major importance attached to them.  Once there is an answer, then the brakes must go on — changing the question requires more care.  Until then...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OP changed the original `char str[20];` to `char *str[20]` which introduced your comment. Changing the question makes comments hard to follow, unless the post wasn't correctly posted. Sorry I was rolling it back before your comment appeared.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just learn about:

> *"I'm having a hard time understanding the process for populating a multidimensional array."*

then forget the string and the char, and do something simple, like use an int. The following code sample shows exactly that.

## Simplest case: Populate multi-dim array of any type

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int arr[2][2];
  int str;
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("please put in a number [%d][%d]: ", i,j);
      scanf("%d", &str);
      arr[i][j] = str;
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("arr[%d][%d] == %d\n", i,j,arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

> ```
> $ ./stackoverflow
> please put in an number[0][0]: 1
> please put in an number[0][1]: 2
> please put in an number[1][0]: 34
> please put in an number[1][1]: 450
>
> arr[0][0] == 1
> arr[0][1] == 2
> arr[1][0] == 34
> arr[1][1] == 450
> ```

## Populate chars

If you want to use *single* characters, then you can use the following code also, BUT you have to take care. `scanf` works in mysterious ways. Notice how the space is there before the `%c`. That is to consume the `\n` that is there you press enter. You can read up [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), but that was the reason for why you had to initially enter twice somet input and press enter. Frankly, I would use something else than `scanf` like `fgets` maybe, but since you used `scanf`, I showed the code which uses it also.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char arr[2][2];
  char str;
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("%s", "please put in a character: ");
      if (scanf(" %c", &str) == 1)  { arr[i][j] = str; }
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("arr[%d][%d] == %c\n", i,j,arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

> ```
> $ ./stackoverflow
> please put in a character: a
> please put in a character: b
> please put in a character: c
> please put in a character: d
>
> arr[0][0] == a
> arr[0][1] == b
> arr[1][0] == c
> arr[1][1] == d
> ```

## Populate Strings

If you want to read strings, then you need to do it a little differently. You need not a 2 dimensional array. You need a 3-dimensional array because the strings are themselves char-arrays. Without a 3D-array you overwrote the 2D array and only got the last value printed multiple times. What was worse, since your multidimensional array is 2x2 while the input string is 1xn, and where n was greater than 2, you would have gotten buffer overflow. The following code fixes these.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char arr[2][2][20];
  char str[20];
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("%s", "please put in a string: ");
      if (scanf("%s", &str[0]) == 1)
      {
          // arr[i][j] = &str[0];
          strncpy(arr[i][j], str, 20);
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      printf("arr[%d][%d] == %s\n", i,j, arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

> ```
> $ ./stackoverflow
> please put in a string: ab
> please put in a string: cd
> please put in a string: ef
> please put in a string: gh
>
> arr[0][0] == ab
> arr[0][1] == cd
> arr[1][0] == ef
> arr[1][1] == gh
> ```

And just for good measure, here is the 4th variation, which uses `char* arr[2][2]` instead of a 3D-char array. It doesn't change much, but like I said, just for good measure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {
    char* arr[2][2];
    char str[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            printf("%s", "please put in a string: ");
            if (scanf("%s", &str[0]) == 1)
            {
                arr[i][j] = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
                strncpy(arr[i][j], str, 20);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            printf("arr[%d][%d] == %s\n", i,j, arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: och, that old buggy `strncpy`.. Note, that your program may overflow on `scanf(" %s", &str[0])`, therefore using `%s` in scanf is no advised. Always limit number of characters, ex. `scanf("%19s", &str[0])`. Also, the space before `%s` is reduntant.

Comment: @KamilCuk, first of all thank you very much for your feedback (since at least the OP, I think has gone to sleep, I thought no one was even paying attention here.) Ok, I learned something then. I didn't know that using `scanf("19s",...` one can limit the number of characters. Thank you for the tip. And I agree, the space before `%s` is redundant,(and I edited my answer accordingly) but just to be sure and since I tested it also, the space before `%c` is not redundant. p.s. why is `strncpy` buggy? Because it doesn't null-terminate?

Comment: Well, yes, because of that. And because of that, strange functions like `lstrcpy` and `strlcpy` exist. Windows banned `strncpy` and only allows `strncpy_s`. There are some online texts about why `strncpy` was a bad design. But in your case, I think it is safe - you know that from `scanf` you will 100% get null terminated string (or undefined behavior) so you can safely use `strncpy`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, ah ok. Thank you very much. I learned something new today.